# Super and Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, super

Beginner's help on Super within Tkinter.

I am trying to understand how to utilize super() within a tkinter app.  I need to reference attributes from parent class.  From code, a button press with super().**init** called, calls another parent and does not reference the info as needed.  with super().**init** not called, i.e. commented out, it throws an attribute error.  Can someone tell me how to call super attributes without rewriting (and overwriting) the original information.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Parent():

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.sym = 'tree'
        self.cl = 3
        self.enter = tk.Entry(master)
        self.enter.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(master,text='text', command= lambda: Child(master))
        self.button.pack()


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self,master):
#        super().__init__(master)
        print(self.enter.get(), self.cl)

root = tk.Tk()
a = Parent(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is highly unusual. Why do you want to make the button create an instance of `Child`? That's not what subclassing is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be doing isn't what subclassing is for. You're trying to use a *new* instance of a class to get the attributes of a *different* instance of a parent class.

The proper way to do subclassing is to *not* create an instance of `Parent`. Instead, create an instance of `Child`. With that, the instance of `Child` will have access to everything in the parent class definition.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Parent():

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.sym = 'tree'
        self.cl = 3
        self.enter = tk.Entry(master)
        self.enter.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(master,text='text', command= self.print_value)
        self.button.pack()

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
        print(self.enter.get(), self.cl)

    def print_value(self):
        print(self.enter.get())


root = tk.Tk()
a = Child(root)
root.mainloop()
```